# Will I be able to install a service as a sudoer?

Tags: rhel, sudo, root, services

I will need to install a custom application as a service on a RHEL 6.2 box this weekend. Will I be able to do this with sudoer powers or will I need the root password for anything?

Comment: It depends both on the application you're installing and exactly how sudoers is configured. In general, though, if you don't need a password to get to root from your regular account, you're probably not going to need it for this application once you transfer the install file to the server.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, the main things I THINK I need to do, are install the config files in /etc/rd.init, and start and stop the service. Can I do both of these with sudoer, not root? The service is application software, so I do not think it needs to be owned by root, it can be owned by me, and I assume it is ok for me to own the init scripts as well.

Comment: being a "sudoer" means you _become_ root after executing "sudo" After you execute "sudo" you can do whatever you want on the system since you will _be_ root at that point.

Comment: Your account shouldn't own the files. If you do the installation after the `sudo` then all the files will be owned as root which is how you want it.

Comment: @TylerDurden what does `sudo -l` say?

Comment: @muru It says I can run ALL commands.

Comment: Woohoo! That's all you need.